# Horizontal repeat x image in footer

Tags: html, css, footer, repeat

I wanted to use "full width" stripe on my footer, but aparently it doesen't want to work. here is the example of what I have right now.:

[image: footer]

I want the footer to do a repeat-x over its div. So, going off until the end of the screen (like its done on the upper part). This might be something extremely simple, but I'm fairly inexperienced with CSS styles, so please lend me a hand.

[EDIT] The footer div is inside a wrapper. The edges of the div are aligned with the wrapper width. My question is if its possible for it to "overlap" the limitations, until the end of the screen.

I would also like to give it a specific position, not variable with the end of the article. I understand that I need to use it as position:absolute, but it always apears right after the header, even if I give it a Y position. There is probably something simple I'm forgetting.

Here is the existent code I have in my Footer class:

```
#footer {
    background:url(wp-content/uploads/2012/06/whitestripe.png) repeat-x;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:16px;
    font-size:11px;
}
#footer a {
    padding:2px 3px;
    color:#004a6a;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#footer a:hover {
    color:#105a7a;
}
```

Thank you.
Marco Roberto.

Comment: is the footer wrapped inside some other element?

Comment: Yes, inside a main wrapper. That is probably limiting. Thats why I'm asking if there is a way for the image to "overlap" the limitations. I should have mentioned that in the question. Editting.

Comment: the we're talking about `overflow-x: visible` for the parent. But then you have to have something like `width: 200%` for the footer itself

Comment: I just tried it and it has some progress. Right now the footer area grew, but only to the right (so not "centered"), and it added a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Is taking the footer outside the main wrapper and making it `position absolute` impossible?

Comment: I dont think that would be a problem (except in the search page, but I believe I could write an exception for it). I don't know how to give it the position I want though.

Comment: `left: 0, right: 0` and something like `bottom: 10px`, if your site has scrollable content and you want the footer to remain in one place, then you can use `position: fixed`, which is absolute in the context of the viewport

Comment: Outstanding. This worked wonders. Please make an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you Jakee.

Comment: there it is, glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the footer element outside the main wrapper so that it isn't constrained by it. Inside the body will do fine for example.

Then change the css:

```
#footer {
  position: absolute; // or fixed if you want it to scroll along
  left: 0;
  right: 0; // or width: 100%
  bottom: 10px; // change to the value you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey now define in your css body and html width

as like this

```
    html, body
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image:url('paper.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-X;
```

Try this

Comment: [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

This will help you to study...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

This will help you to study...